# In pre-tribulation pre-millennialism, will those who have died before the millennium return to earth?

Tags: eschatology, premillennialism, tribulation

Let's just say God raptures his church in the next few years and we are alive to experience it. We survive the 7 remaining years. Then the "Glorious Appearance" happens and God sets up his 1000 year reign on Earth.

Will our loved ones come down from Heaven to live on Earth with us? Or will we have to live 1000 years with God on Earth before returning to Heaven to see our loved ones? How does that work? Will Heaven on Earth and Heaven become one so that way we will all be able to live together? Or will (Heaven on Earth) and (Heaven) still be two separate places until God takes us up to heaven after his 1000 year reign?

Comment: According to whom? There are a number of teachings. You'll have to be more specific to get a good answer here.

Comment: You speak of Heaven as if it were a physical place as Earth is; but heaven resides in the Spiritual Realm and just may be a state of being. We may or may not enter into a physical place since Revelation states that the old heaven and Earth had passed away. It is not something we as mere humans could possibly know. try Studying Jesus remarks concerning Heaven. A download from the internet 'What the Bible says about' can be of invaluable help in that.

Comment: According to one view, when a person dies, he is put in a holding place called Paradise (Abraham's Bosom) in the midst of the earth. At Christ's coming those "asleep in Jesus" will rise first, then the living, and they will live and reign with Christ 1000 years. Then the judgment takes place when the rest of the dead rise, and some loved ones can be reunited at that point if their names are in the book of life.

Answer (score 1):

According to Theopedia, in classical dispensationalism men, angels and Christ will return to the earth.

> Classic dispensationalists (ala C. I. Scofield and Lewis Sperry Chafer) are pre-tribulationists and believe that the second coming will be in two stages separated by a 7-year period of tribulation. At the first he will return in the air to rescue those who are Christians at that time (the rapture). Then follows a seven-year period of suffering in which the Antichrist will conquer the world and kill those who refuse to worship him. At the end of the seven years, the final witness will go out before men and angels and Christ will return to the earth. He will defeat the Antichrist, and rescue the Jews and those who have converted to Christianity during the tribulation period.

http://www.theopedia.com/premillennialism

Wikipedia says the same thing.

> Dispensational premillennialism[64] generally holds that Israel and the Church are distinct entities.[65] It also widely holds to the pretribulational return of Christ, which believes that Jesus will return to take up Christians into heaven by means of a rapture immediately before a seven-year worldwide tribulation. This will be followed by an additional return of Christ with his saints (though there are post tribulation dispensationalists, such as Robert Gundry).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premillennialism